# How to prompt data on piped commands

Tags: pipe, prompt

I'm trying to use this command:

```
mysqldump --opt --hex-blob \
    -h source -p xxxx -u user1 \
    source_db | \
    mysql \
    -h target -p yyyy -u user2 \
    target_db
```

So, how can I rewrite it to avoid setting passwords on `-p` and be asked instead

Comment: If I leave the `-p` blank I'll be asked for a password but the pipe breaks this behavior on the first command

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kusalananda and @Barun

I've used a script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

USER1=
PASS1=
USER2=
PASS2=

mysqldump --opt --hex-blob \
    -h source_host -p"$PASS1" -u "$USER1" \
    source_db | \
    mysql \
    -h target_host -p"$PASS2" -u "$USER2" \
    target_db
```